# How to find stored procedure that point to another DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I a server I have three database with the following structure:

> **DatabaseA**
>
> - SP_A01 => is a stored procedure defined as `INSERT INTO T_A01([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[T_A04]`
> - SP_A02 => is a stored procedure defined as `INSERT INTO T_A01([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [DatabaseB].[dbo].[T_B02]`
> - SP_A03 => is a stored procedure defined as `INSERT INTO T_A01([Id]) SELECT [Id] FROM [DatabaseC].[dbo].[T_C02]`
> - T_A01 => is a table
> - T_A02 => is a table
> - T_A03 => is a table
> - T_A04 => is a table
>
> **DatabaseB**
>
> - T_B01 => is a table
> - T_B02 => is a table
>
> **DatabaseC**
>
> - T_C01 => is a table
> - T_C02 => is a table
> - T_C03 => is a table

I would like to make a query which finds all the SP of DatabaseA that points to a database different from DatabaseA.
In the example above, the query should give the following result:

- SP_A02
- SP_A03

because they point to DatabaseB and DatabaseC.

**What I've tryed**

I have the following query to find all the SP in the DatabaseA but I can't understand how to tell the system to show only the ones who point out of DatabaseA.

```
select * from DatabaseA.information_schema.routines where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id),
       OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id),
       referenced_database_name,
       referenced_entity_name
FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE  referenced_database_name <> DB_NAME() /*Not NULL and not current DB*/
       AND OBJECTPROPERTY(referencing_id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

After creating the following proc

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[P1]
AS
    EXEC Foobar.dbo.DFG

    SELECT [Id]
    FROM   [DatabaseB].[dbo].[T_B02]
```

It returns

```
+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| (No column name) | (No column name) | referenced_database_name | referenced_entity_name |
+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| dbo              | P1               | Foobar                   | DFG                    |
| dbo              | P1               | DatabaseB                | T_B02                  |
+------------------+------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```